# Nested for/if loop and statement

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested

```
if (first statement) 
{
    for (first loop) 
    {
        if (second statement) 
        {
            for (second loop) 
            {       
                if (third statement) 
                {
                    Do something;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, if the third statement is false , it is going to the first loop or second ? c#

Comment: Just try it and you will see what happens.

Comment: What happens when you test it?

Comment: Of course it is the second loop first, then first loop terminates at last.

Comment: yes I got it while drawing a block scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the third statement is false, you will simply continue your second `for` loop, as it is just one iteration of this `for` loop. You will stay in it until the condition keeping you in the for loop is not verified anymore. Then you will get back to your first `for` loop with the same reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

If the third if is false it will finish the for loop where it belongs to after it will finish the second loop until the if is true or just finish and go back to the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
if (first statement) {
for (first loop) {
if (second statement) {
for (second loop) {
if (third statement) { // if false, will still do what comes after here
Do something;
}
if{ 4th statement // will still do this.
}
} 
}
}
}
```

will still do the loop